# Dynamic CPT / Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I use multiple CPT / Taxonomies / Terms in my website.

Currently, to customize, and use the good WP template, i've made a `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php` file for each CPT.

But in fact, it's ONLY the CPT and Taxonomy words who are different in my templates.

is exist a solution to make it dynamic ?

---

**UPDATED QUESTION**

By saying dynamic, I mean :

Is possible to use only the `taxonomy.php` template instead of `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php` template and have the `'post_type => '$post_type'` and `'taxonomy' => '$taxonomy'` dynamic

-> What am i trying to achieve is to reduce the templates collection tu use only one because the difference between all my `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php` is only *post_type* and *taxonomy*.

---

Bellow, the start of my loop :

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'cocktails', // Make it dynamic ?
    'posts_per_page'        => 1,
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'catcocktails', // Make it dynamic ?
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => get_queried_object()->slug,
        )
    ),
);

    // Custom query.
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Check that we have query results.
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        // Start looping over the query results.
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            $query->the_post(); 

?>
```

Comment: Hey WDCreativ, I honestly don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you mean `dynamic` in the sense of querying multiple content types? Or dynamic as in "get all content types and then loop through them"? What exactly do you want to achieve? Could you please update your question for clarification?

Comment: Hello @leymannx, thanks for your answer. I've updated my question :)

Answer (score 1):

If your custom taxonomies are unique to the custom post type, then you can set post type to an array ie `post_type => array('cpt1', 'cpt2'),` knowing that the taxonomy filter will only return the relevant post types.

Secondly, in your tax_query, change `catcocktails` to `get_queried_object()->taxonomy` which will make it "dynamic".